# Mediawiki custom temp directory = safe?

Tags: mediawiki

I ran unto an issue when upgrading from 1.24.0 to 1.27.0.

Since I'm on a shared server and have multiple Mediawiki installations, the system temp folder is being shared across them all. This is causing a MWException error on page load. Obviously this will cause problems since temp content of one wiki will overwrite the content of another.

So I've declared a custom temp directory: *(Paste into LocalSettings.php)*

```
$wgTmpDirectory = "$IP/images/temp";
```

**While this fixes the issue, I'm not sure it's a secure practice. I see many other people using this fix... But is it safe to have the temp folder PUBLICLY visible?**

[This documentation](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgTmpDirectory) is all I can find explaining what is dumped into the temp folder. And here is a [bug report](https://phabricator.wikimedia.org/T127127) of the root issue.

Comment: A saner approach is to use something like `<your system temp folder>/mediawiki/<wikiname>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that I've stumbled across a solid answer.

Instead we can point to the default tmp directory by using [$wgUploadDirectory](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgUploadDirectory). Then we can dump the temp files into a unique sub-directory.

Custom temp directory code: *(Paste into LocalSettings.php)*

`$wgTmpDirectory = "{$wgUploadDirectory}/tmp/uniquename";`